# Free fall of two point particles in general relativity vs. Newtonian mechanics

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, free-fall

In general relativity (GR) the equation of free fall of two point particles which start from rest at some finite distance $r_i$ is strikingly similar to the equation of free fall in Newtonian mechanics for the same situation. The equation in general relativity (taken from "The mathematical theory of black holes" by S. Chandrasekar, eq. (104) in ch. 3, rewritten in terms of $r$ instead of the auxiliary variable $\eta$) is
$$
\tau(r) = \sqrt{\frac{r_i^3}{2GM}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{r_i}\left(1-\frac{r}{r_i}\right)}+\arccos\sqrt{\frac{r}{r_i}}\right), \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time and $r$ the distance between the particles; $G$ is the gravitational constant and $M$ the mass of the heavier particle, that is considered at rest in the one-body problem solved by the Schwarzchild metric.

Instead in Newtonian mechanics (see e.g. the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall) the equation obtained by solving the two-body problem is
$$
t(r) = \sqrt{\frac{r_i^3}{2G(M+m)}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{r_i}\left(1-\frac{r}{r_i}\right)}+\arccos\sqrt{\frac{r}{r_i}}\right), \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
where $t$ is the time and $m$ is the mass of the lighter particle.

So, my question is: considering the two-body problem in general relativity (I don't know if it has been solved even for this very simple situation), do we obtain a solution like \eqref{eq2} also for the proper time (i.e. equation \eqref{eq1} with $M+m$ instead of simply $M$) of each particle?

Even if the two-body problem has not been solved, I don't expect a large difference with respect to \eqref{eq2} or at least when the free-fall time is calculated:
$$
t_{\rm ff} = \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac{r_i^3}{2G(M+m)}}, \tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
because general relativity must replicate Newtonian mechanics in ordinary situations; the main difference in this instance is that in GR we deal with proper time instead of absolute time as in Newtonian mechanics (comparision with coordinate time is not possible, because the particles never collide as seen by a stationary observer that employs coordinate time). However, maybe there are other considerations that suggest a different solution.